# Trying to use raw_input from another function

Tags: python

from sys import exit

```
def start():
    print "You woke up in a dungeon"
    print "There is three weapon in front of you"
    print "A sword, a staff and dagger"
    print "Which one do you choose"

choice = raw_input("")
if choice == "dagger":
    print "A rogue huh?"
elif choice == "staff":
    print "A wizard how interesting..."
elif choice == "sword":
    print "A warrior."
else:
    print "..."
dungeon_path()

def dungeon_path():
    if choice == "dagger":
        print "Which way you choose rogue"

start()
```

I wanna print the last line if I choosed dagger in first function but I can't seem to get it work I tried to give choice a value and then used "if" but it didn't work that way either so what do I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `choice` variable as an argument to the `dungeon_path` function:

```
...
        print "..."
    dungeon_path(choice)

def dungeon_path(choice):
    if choice == "dagger":
        print "Which way you choose rogue"
```